# Clearfix не работает

Tags: css

Не могу понять, почему не работает clearfix. В данном макете футер должен очиститься от float, но почему-то не выходит.

```css
header {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: #336596;
}

nav {
  border: 1px solid black;
  float: left;
  width: 15%;
  background-color: #fd9800;
}

main {
  border: 1px solid black;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 60%;
}

aside {
  border: 1px solid black;
  float: left;
  width: 15%;
  background-color: #983264;
}

footer {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: #669900;

}

.clearfix::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}
```

```html
  <header>
    <h1>Header</h1>
  </header>

  <div class"clearfix">
    <nav>
      <h2>Navigation</h2>
    </nav>
    <main>
      <h2>Main</h2>
    </main>
    <aside>
      <h2>Related links</h2>
    </aside>
  </div>

  <footer>
    <h1>Footer</h1>
  </footer>
```

Должен получится вот такой макет [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: в смысле вот так надо ? https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/NVNgRY

Comment: Да! Похоже, проблема юыла в том, что clearfix нужно было вывести в отдельный div сразу после aside

Comment: а щас же 2019 ? и самое оно применять flex или grid а float применять только для обтекания ...и всё и всё что вы там колдуете у вас получится автоматически ...

Comment: https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/BeKZgq  вот это flex смотрите как просто

Comment: Спасибо! Все стало понятно )

Comment: Да, flex удобнее. Но так как это задание для обучения, пришлось и в float разобраться )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не работало потому что вы не поставили **=** после класса  `class="clearfix"`